# IIS in Docker returning 403

Tags: docker, iis, iis-8, docker-for-windows

I have a Docker image with the ASP.NET dependencies added and a website with a single `index.html`.

The DockerFile is:

```
# escape=`
FROM iis-with-asp
ADD ./Ping C:/Ping
RUN ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\icacls.exe", "\"C:\\Ping\"", "/grant", "\"IIS AppPool\\DefaultAppPool\":(OI)(CI)", "/T"]
RUN ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\icacls.exe", "\"C:\\Ping\"", "/grant", "\"IIS_IUSRS\":(OI)(CI)", "/T"]
RUN ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\icacls.exe", "\"C:\\Ping\"", "/grant", "\"Network Service\":(OI)(CI)", "/T"]
RUN ["\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\AppCmd.exe", "add",  "sites",  "/name:\"Ping\"", "/id:2", "/bindings:http://localhost:9000", "/physicalPath:C:\\Ping"]
EXPOSE 9000
RUN ["\\Windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\AppCmd.exe", "list", "site"]
```

It's build with:

```
docker build -t u .
```

and running it with:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 u
```

When I hit `http://localhost:9000` with Fiddler I get a 409 though.

Comment: You ever found a solution?

Comment: @cheeesus I did, it was a crazy permissions thing that I didn't really understand.  Anyhow, gymnastics with `ical.exe` was the answer.

Comment: @BanksysSan please post your solution or Dockerfile that finally worked. I’m having the same issue. Windows 10, Docker and 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

your exposing 9000 port to host machine, you should access with 9000 port only but make sure that you're exporting correct application port.    ex: (host machine)9000:5000(app port)

Comment: I'm exporting 9000.  9000 is the port the website is bond to.

Comment: Isn't the syntax `-p Internal_Port:External_Port`?

Comment: Ah, it's the other way around.  OK, the real problem is the 403 response though.